# Aligning shapefile to satellite imagery

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, georeferencing, alignment

I have a line shapefile in ArcGIS 10.1 (road shapefile) in WGS datum but they are not exactly placed as in the Satellite image. Is there a way to adjust all those lines to places on Arial image?

Comment: Can you please supply more information such as what type of satellite data you are working with and how the vector data were derived?

Answer (score 2):

Provided the Aerial Image is accurate to your project needs and you have re-projected the Line Shapefile to match the spatial reference of the Image, you can use the [Spatial Adjustment Toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m800000030000000) to get started with some semi-automated fixes to your line data.

Answer (score 2):

Inacurracy is a way of life for the GIS professional. Depending on the source of your roads they could be many metres from their correct location; normally data comes with metadata which should contain a date and an approximate accuracy figure. For example 250k data will be mostly within 125 metres of its' correct location, conversely GPS tracklogs will usually be within 5 metres of the true location.

As the roads were probably drawn (digitized) from a different image at a different time or possibly even GPS recorded they will be different to what is on your satellite image, this is known as temporal change.

You have options:

1. Redraw the roads using the ones you've got as a reference (long time).
2. If you're sure the roads are accurate then transform the image to match your roads using [GeoReference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t000000mq000000) (not 100% match)
3. If you are sure the image is correct then warp the roads to match the image using [Spatial adjustment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m800000030000000) toolbar ([rubber sheet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m60000005m000000)) (still not 100% match).
4. Accept that this is the way that it is and draw your roads with a thick line so map users can't tell that they're slightly off.

You have to make a decision based on how inaccurate the roads are, how much you *trust* each source and how much time/effort you are prepared to invest on getting the data to match.